# How can I change a object's (present in a list) field?

Tags: c#, list

For example:  There's a list : `list<student> Students` .
It consists of `{ Id, Name, Marks}` where id is unique.
Suppose I want to change marks of a particular object. How do I do it?

Comment: Are you saying, without actually saying, that you have an `Id` value and you want to get the item with that `Id`? If so, what's stopping you comparing that property of each item with the value? There are other, possibly better, ways but I find it hard to believe that you don't know how to write a loop, which would work perfectly well. I don't see that you've put much thought into the problem.

Comment: `Suppose I want to change marks of a particular object.` - don’t understand it, sorry

Comment: Hint: If you want to save students by ID and access them by ID, it's better to use a Dictionary: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply access the objects by index and change their fields:

```cs
Students[0].Marks = 100; // changing the mark of the 0th student to 100, assuming Marks is an int
Students[1].Marks = 90;
// etc...
```

Comment: This assumes that the properties are writable. Good object design would make them immutable.

Comment: You can use getters and setters to define any additional processing you want to do when a field gets reassigned or read.

Comment: Yes, you can. You can also use `goto` when you code, but it isn't a good idea. Settable properties are not necessarily good design, particularly for business objects.

Answer (score 2):

So based on answers and comments, I have come to following conclusion and it works as desired.

```
int targetId;  //can be taken input
int newValue;  //can be taken input
...
for (int i = 0; i < Students.Count(); i++)
  if(Students[i].Id == targetId)
    Students[i].Marks = newValue;
```

I will also try to explore dictionary approach to handle data.

Comment: Lol. I uploaded my answer so that I can mark it as solved. But it appears that I can't mark my answer as solved in 2 days.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. `Student[i]` is clearly not an integer.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks. I changed it to `Student[i].Id`.

Comment: You also have `Student` versus `Students`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that this is a more modern way of doing what you need:

```
var student = Students.Where(s => s.Id == targetId).FirstOrDefault();
if (student != null)
{
    student.Marks = newValue;
}
```